# Replace in Linux

Tags: linux, string, replace, sed

i want to replace string pattern which looks like -

```
1234..5678 9876 4567 8245..9745
```

I want to make this look like -

```
{1234..5678} 9876 4567 {8245..9745}
```

I tried `:%s/....\.\...../\{....\.\.....\}/g` in vi editor. But its not giving the desired output. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's#[0-9]\{4\}\.\.[0-9]\{4\}#{&}#g' file.txt
```

In `vim`:

```
:%s/[0-9]\{4\}\.\.[0-9]\{4\}/{&}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
~$ echo 1234..5678 9876 4567 8245..9745 | sed  's/\([0-9]\{4\}\.\.[0-9]\{4\}\)/{\1}/g'
{1234..5678} 9876 4567 {8245..9745}
```